# Is there a way to initiate the array only once?

Tags: java, arrays

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class User
{
   private static int [] users;

   public User(){
       
            users = new int[10];
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            int InputNumber = input.nextInt();
            int length = String.valueOf(InputNumber).length();
```

I have an method that calls this one, but I believe it's that everytime I do it, it creates an array, or that's what I think it does.

Down here is just a bunch of code to make verifications and add the number to the array.

```
      if(length != 8 || InputNumber < 0){
            System.out.println("That number isn't valid, try again, the number must have 8 digits");
            User menu = new User();
            return;
        }else{    
             int i = -1;
         do{ 
             i++;
             continue;
        }while((users[i] != 0 && users[i] == InputNumber) );
            
         if(i == users.length){
            System.out.println("There's enough space, delete users");           
        }else if(users[i] != 0 && users[i] == InputNumber){
            System.out.println("That user already exists");
        }else{
            System.out.println("The user " + InputNumber + " as been added!");
            users[i] = InputNumber;
        }  
            //show a menu
      }
    }
```

There aren't any errors and I can create a user but the thing is, every time I try to create another one it looks like it creates another array, I think. What I want to know is what can I change to make this work.

Comment: `User menu = new User()` is **recursive** and not what you want. You should break your logic up into methods. Don't put everything into a no arg constructor.

Comment: Technically you could add another static variable, like `private static boolean initialized = false;`, and do the initialization only when it's false, then set it to true. However it's a very questionable design, why is that field `static` if you want to initialize it from a constructor?

Comment: This code needs serious refactor, I get the idea that you "return" to menu by creating new `User` but that is not a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the array field is static and your initializing the array in the constructor everytime your creating a new User object your reinitializing the array and losing all the information that was there.

If you really need to have that field static simply initiate in the same line like this:

```
private static int [] users = new int[10];
```

Other thing you could do if you really want to initialize the field in the constructor is to check if the array is null or not:

```
if(users == null) {
    users = new int[10];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With your example all you need is to initialize array once is to actually initialize it only once:

`private static final int[] users = new int[10];`

Answer (score 1):

You can do 2 things:

1. replace this code for your static line
   `private static int [] users = new int[10];`
   and delete initialization in constructor
2. or you can check for null reference in constructor
   `if(users == null) users = new int[10];`